# How to create stub/services files with MATLAB grpc plugin?

Tags: matlab, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I'm using [MatlabWithProtoV3](https://github.com/BraunPhilipp/protobuf-matlab) to create protoc.exe with matlab_out in Windows environment.
I was able to create protoc and when I use

```
protoc.exe user.proto --matlab_out=./
```

It only creating matlab files for proto messages (files can be found in the bottom attachment) and it is not creating matlab files for services(client and server)

Then, I read about plugins and included the generator and plugin files to [gRPC Source](https://github.com/grpc/grpc) to create Matlab plugin and created the grpc_matlab_plugin.exe successfully.

Now, when I execute

```
protoc.exe user.proto --matlab_out=./ --grpc_out=./ --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="D:\grpc\cmake\build\Debug\grpc_matlab_plugin.exe
```

I'm getting

```
pb_descriptor_LoginRequest.m: Tried to write the same file twice.
 pb_read_LoginRequest.m: Tried to write the same file twice. 
pb_descriptor_APIResponse.m: Tried to write the same file twice. 
pb_read_APIResponse.m: Tried to write the same file twice.
 pb_descriptor_Empty.m: Tried to write the same file twice. 
pb_read_Empty.m: Tried to write the same file twice.
```

error message and no files are getting created.

in gRPC repo, for C++ compiler i could find [cpp_plugin.h](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/compiler/cpp_plugin.h) has some codes to create service related files but similar file is not available for Matlab in [here](https://github.com/farsounder/protobuf-matlab/tree/master/src/farsounder/protobuf/compiler/matlab) or [here](https://github.com/BraunPhilipp/protobuf-matlab/tree/master/src/farsounder/protobuf/compiler/matlab)

Can you please let me know how to create Matlab files for services?

Attached the files created when I execute the above mentioned commands,
[sample_files.zip](https://github.com/farsounder/protobuf-matlab/files/7856503/userproto_matlabfiles.zip)

[Github issue](https://github.com/farsounder/protobuf-matlab/issues/17)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`protobuf-matlab`](https://github.com/farsounder/protobuf-matlab) is just a *protobuf* plugin - it generates code to read/write protocol buffer.

Unfortunately it does not implement a *gRPC* plugin which would build the client stub and server.

If you are able to call your matlab code from another language, you could host the gRPC server externally, e.g. create a gRPC server in dotnet and use COM to call your matlab code.

Comment: i'll try that.. thanks for your time